# Cycle through multiple background colors - Seeking code improvement

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Check out my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pqyxM/5/)

Here is the js in question:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.clickMe').toggle(
        function() {
            $('#coloredDiv').css({
                "background-color": "#eeeeee"
            })
        }, function() {
            $('#coloredDiv').css({
                "background-color": "#00ff00"
            })
        }, function() {
            $('#coloredDiv').css({
                "background-color": "#ff0000"
            })
        }, function() {
            $('#coloredDiv').css({
                "background-color": "#000000"
            })
        });
});
```

The goal: each time the link is clicked ("click me") the background color of the #coloredDiv should change to one of the following colors in the order provided: #eeeeee, #00ff00, #ff0000, #000000 .  Once the last color is reached, if the link is clicked again, the cycle should start over from the first color listed.

The code works but I would like to know: is the code in its current form respectable or is it not so good?  Am I making poor choices?  What other way could this be written to achieve the same result but in perhaps a slightly better (i.e. more elegant) way?

Lastly, you'll notice that upon page load the square has no default color.  I've toyed with the idea of defaulting to #eeeeee upon load but I realize that I would then need to account for this using a conditional statement to check the current color and then apply the appropriate color depending on the situation.  Any guidance on how to approach writing this would be greatly appreciated.

Please note that I want to accomplish this task using only jQuery and no plugins.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DRYing it a bit:

```
  var counter = 0;
  var colors = [
    "#eeeeee",
    "#00ff00",
    "#ff0000",
    "#000000"      
  ];

  var $div = $('#coloredDiv');

  $('.clickMe').click(function(){

    $div.css({
        "background-color": colors[(counter++)%colors.length]
    })

  });
```

With the modulo operator [`%`], you loop over the array without exceeding its bounds [`a%b`evaluates to `b-1` at most].

EDIT: you just increment the counter, then the modulo will "reset" it to 0 every `array.length` iterations [it won't be reset actually, just the result of the expression will look like]. Search wikipedia for modulo operator, you will find out a lot of interesting properties.

```
  i | (i++)%arr.length
---------
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 |
   ...
```

Comment: It would also be fun to have jQuery cycle through the digits in an rgba colour values!

Comment: Moonwave99: that's absolutely amazing.  After I posted, the idea came to me to create an array and loop through it and then apply the color but what you did beyond what I would have been able to do.

Question regarding colors[(counter++)%colors.length]. I understand the use of % but making sense of this altogether isn't so clear.  Could you explain it briefly?  You are creating the index of the array based on upon the remainder of counter++ and the array length?

Comment: Last follow up: was my original code pretty bad? Not so good but not so bad? Pathetic?

Comment: I also noticed that when I try to place console.log(colors[(counter++)%colors.length]);
it messes up the code completely so it won't run properly.  have not see this before with console.log

Comment: @max7 this is because you increment the counter even in the `console.log` statement, with `counter++` - if you want to inspect what's happening under the hood, save it to a temporary variable. Your code was not bad, just didn't scale well in case you wanted to use more colors, because you had to add a whole function every time; use arrays for that ^^

Answer (score 2):

Don't know better or not but have a look at the following:

```
<div id="coloredDiv" data-index="-1"></div>
```

Note the `data` attribute added to div.

```
var colors = ['#eeeeee', "#00ff00", "#ff0000", "#000000"];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $colorDiv = $('#coloredDiv');
    ln = colors.length;
    $('.clickMe').on("click", function () {
        var i = $colorDiv.data("index");
        ++i;
        if (i >= ln) i = 0;
        $colorDiv.css({
            'background-color': colors[i]
        });
        $colorDiv.data("index", i);
    });
});
```

Working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/pqyxM/8/).

Comment: This is very good as well although it appears to be skipping the first color #eeeeee when you click on the link the first time.

Comment: I fixed it: change the initial value in data-index to -1 and all is well :)

Comment: Thanks! Question: since we are working off the click event, do we really need to have $(document).ready(etc ..)?  Could we not just declare our array and other variables then start with $('.clickMe').on("click", ...)?  Or would this be considered a bad practice?

Comment: well `$(document).ready(function(){});` means that the `DOM` is ready and loaded and you are not adding handlers to non-existing object or not accessing the elements that are not yet in `DOM`. Though now days the syntax for this script is like `$(function(){})`

Comment: You can simplify a bit with `i = ++i % ln;` and by chaining the jQuery `$colorDiv.css("background-color", colors[i]).data("index", i);` [See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xr280xr/ct5r641j/5/)