# Cycling through colors in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm new to HTML/CSS/jQuery and am doing a pointless project to try to get familiar with some basic features. I want clicking on various cells in a table to change attributes of other cells, cycling through colors.

I've tried to take guidance from this answer: [Cycle through multiple background colors - Seeking code improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409365/cycle-through-multiple-background-colors-seeking-code-improvement), but my attempts have all failed. Toggling would be easiest, but that's apparently no longer a thing, and I can't figure out why my alternative solution (inspired by this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/pqyxM/8/) doesn't work:

```
var main = function () {
    var colors = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'purple', 'green'];
    var ln = colors.length;

    $('#textswitch').click(function() {
        var i = $('#holder').data('index');
        ++i;
        if (i >= ln) i = 0;
        $('texty').css('color', colors[i]);
        $('#holder').data('index', i);
    }); 
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

I suspect I'm committing some horrible crime like mixing JavaScript and jQuery elements, but I don't know enough to be sure or to fix it. Can someone who knows more about this shed some light on it? My full Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/sishu7/mq7jgjgL/2/, but obviously this part of it is not working.

Comment: Well, this code *should* work. Do you have a non working fiddle for us?

Comment: Here : http://jsfiddle.net/mq7jgjgL/4/

Comment: The code worked for me too :-)

Comment: Guys , she wants to change it each click!!! according to the colors in the site ( cycle through colors)

Comment: Yes, I want it to cycle through colors. (Eventually for the title, image, text, etc., but for now I'm just working on making the "texty" class cycle.) My non-working fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/sishu7/mq7jgjgL/2/. It's probably something stupid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var main = function () {
    var colors = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'purple', 'green'];
    var ln = colors.length;
    var curr = 0;
    $('#textswitch').click(function() {
        $('.texty').css('color', colors[curr]);
        $('#holder').data('index', curr);
        curr++;
        if (curr >= ln)
            curr = 0;
    }); 
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/mq7jgjgL/6/)

You were also missing a `.` before `texty` in your selector.

Comment: That works--thank you so much! Now that the index is being stored in curr, though, is there any point to attaching it to #holder as a data-index attribute?

Comment: Not that I can think of =) easier to store variable than within DOM element.

Comment: Great! This allowed me to get all of it working really quickly: http://jsfiddle.net/sishu7/mq7jgjgL/7/. Thanks again.